# Continuous function such that image of closed set is not closed

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone give me an example of a continuous function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ such that the image of a closed set is not closed? I can't seem to think of one but my friend insists that one exists.

Comment: Do you mean that the image of **every** closed set isn't closed, or that the image of an **one** closed set isn't closed?

Answer (score 3):

The inverse tangent function, for example, maps $\mathbb R\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

You will not find an example of a continuous function that sends a closed interval into a non-closed set, because continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets.

Comment: To add to this, it follows that the image of a closed set is not arbitrary, since any closed set is a countable union of compact sets, so the continuous image of a closed set is always a countable union of closed sets (an $F_\sigma$ set).

Answer (score 2):

Consider $e^{-x}$. Then $[0,\infty)$ goes to?

Comment: How is $[0, \, \infty)$ a closed set?

Comment: @RachelJacobsen What are its limit points?

Comment: @RachelJacobsen How is $[0,\infty)$ *not* a closed set? =)